# Defining a getter setter for a child property of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a moderately complex hierarchical javascript object and at each node of the object is one or more properties consisting of an array of simple objects. The object is accessed via a tree view and the simple array of objects shown as a collection of textboxes for the selected node using ng-repeat. e.g.

```
var myObj = { children: { childid: { props: [{id: "prop1", val: "<div></div>"}] } } };
```

The trouble is that text in the textbox is HTML and I want to escape/unescape the text as it's written/read. If it was a top level scope object I could use a getter/setter defined in the scope (ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }").

Is the only alternative to walk the whole tree and use Object.defineProperty on every detail record to set up the a getter/setter? This seems a bit contrived and long-winded.

**Edit:**

I'm binding the property to a textbox so the property needs to be assignable.

Comment: Ok, so it seems you just need to wrap your getter/setter in a service/factory, to use it anywhere, injecting it in controllers.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but I would do it in another way. May be place a custom directive on the `textarea` to auto escape/unescape.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `$scope.myMethod` to do the job, but this job could be run on any $scope, you just have to append your method to `$rootScope`, then it will be available :

- on any controller via `$rootScope.myMethod()`.
- and on any template via `<div ng-bind="myMethod(myObject)">`

But you could (and should) also **write a clean angularjs filter to do this job**.
See there to [the doc about filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)
And there [is the official tutorial to create custom] filters(https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)

Then you could use it like that in your templates, in your whole application :

```
<div>
    {{ myObject.myPropertie | myFilter }}
</div>
```

Comment: Will the filter operate on both getting and setting or just get? (will try and see what happens)

Comment: Yes filters permit to transform your data, often in order to display it (so, as getter). But in controller/factory you can use it in the other way. Although I think in your case you could store the escaped HTML content in your myObject.myProperty, and use a custom filter in the template to display it.

Comment: Hmm, the filter is no help - it's unassignable so I can't use it in ng-model. Same deal with ng-model="func(prop)" too.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is surely to using the `ng-bind-html` angular attribute.

This use the angular **Strict Contextual Escaping services**.

As a directive in your templates, and as service in controllers and factories :

```
<input ng-model="userHtml">
<div ng-bind-html="userHtml"></div>
```

See the documentation here : [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: I don't see how this helps. I want to put text, which happens to be HTML markup in a textbox for the user to edit. The text in the textbox should be markup but escaped when persisted/transmitted. I may just leave it unescaped as (thinking about it) it will never be injected into an HTML page but only ever delivered as JSON object in a js file. The default JSON escaping should suffice.